# Calculate integration with Euler integration

Tags: integration

Calculate:
$$\int^{\pi /2}_{0}\tan ^{\alpha} x dx$$
with $| \alpha|<1$

Answer: $\pi/(2 \cos \frac{\alpha \pi}{2})$

> In $B$ function or integral, we have $B(x,y)=\int^{1}_{0}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ which is defined on interval $(0,1)$, but the problem listed above seems out of range with $\alpha$ uncertain. Thank you for your help.

Edit: The previous one seems broken... thanks for @curiousguest

Comment: You don't need Euler's beta function to evaluate this one: $\int\tan\alpha x\,dx=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln|\cos\alpha x|+C$. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Oh, I know what's wrong. I can get $- \frac{1}{\alpha} \ln(|\cos \frac{\pi}{2} \alpha|)$ as result. But how could it be the same as the answer listed above?

Comment: It's actually not the same, that's why I asked if you have written the right integral.

Comment: Yes that's what is given on book. Maybe we should ignore it? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Oh, I got it. The function should be $\tan^\alpha x$, then your answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, show that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^\alpha x\cos^\beta x\,dx=\frac12\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2},\frac{1+\beta}{2}\right)$$ by substitution $t=\sin^2 x$. Then your integral is $$I=\frac12\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2},\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1+\alpha}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1-\alpha}{2})}{2\Gamma(1)}=\frac12\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2\sin\pi(\frac{1-\alpha}{2})}$$ by Euler's reflection formula.